# How to stop a style being applied to a table

Tags: html, css

I'm setting cell padding on a HTML table using : `cellpadding: 10`

A padding style is being inherited which causes the cellpadding to not be set :

[image]

So if I deselect the padding checkbox above (in Chrome) the cellpadding is applied correctly. How can I prevent the "padding: 0" style being set on my table. I've tried using !important on the cellspacing but this does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Try appling inline style with `!important` instead of stylesheets

Comment: Can you show your html and css please?

Comment: Make a more specific selector. Oh, and try to never use !important whenever possible.

Comment: try looking in these link for your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889565/avoid-css-styles-applying-to-child-elements

Comment: !important is a blunt tool of a desperate coder. The rest of us use specificity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd avoid using the cellpadding attribute and use CSS to control your presentation.

It looks as though you're using a css reset to zero out browser default values so you simple need to re-define them where needed:

```
th, td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating more specific selectors. Something like

```
#myBody .myDiv table th, #myBody .myDiv table th {
    padding: 10px;
}
```